# Advantages of cloud-init runcmd over a user data 'shell' script

Tags: cloud-init

Other than the order of execution (cloud_config_modules v cloud_final_modules respectively), what reason would I have to use [runcmd](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/modules.html#runcmd) over a [user data script](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/explanation/format.html#user-data-script) in a cloud-init setup?

Comment: If you're not using any other features of the cloud-config file format, I see no reason to use `runcmd` over simply passing in a shell script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no other advantage unless you're using the cloud-config for other purposes. Passing a shell script (starting with `#!`) will generally be easier than using runcmd.